# Setting up my first VPS

Tags: vps, tomcat

I am setting up my first VPS.

I have managed to download and install Tomcat on the VPS.

It is my first time using a VPS service and i am a bit lost.

When I enter my VPS IP on the browser (just the IP itself) it says:

```
The page isn't working (my ip: xxx) didn't send any data ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
```

Then when I run Tomcat on my server and try going to `myip:8080` i get this error:

```
This site can’t be reached
The web page at https://xxx.xxxx.xxx/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT
```

What do I need to do? What are my next steps? I am a bit lost but my idea was hosting multiple websites with Apache Tomcat on the same VPS.

Comment: What do the cert details show? Is this a server that you own, control, and host, or are you paying for a VPS and trying to install something on it? If the latter, it seems you probably need to spend a bit of time researching setting up a web server on a VPS, confirming your config meets the requirements of your host, etc. If this is a device you control entirely, that's just more research you need to be doing, and more information you need to give us in order for us to understand what's going on.

Comment: Also, that "1" at the beginning makes me wonder if you've copied this question from someplace else.

Comment: Hi, yes its a VPS i purchased for a month to learn a bit more about handling a VPS with hostinger. The idea was hosting nodejs and java websites. Since both of these are diffrent technologies and apache tomcat is needed for running the java websites i built, i was trying to run them on apache. I felt close since i had started apache and it was running, but it seems to be redirecting me somewhere else. Sorry i did copy this question (which is my own) from serverFault, they recommended me to ask here =)

Comment: There are a few problems: This site is about computer hardware and software, not really about web server configs. Your question indicates you have a knowledge gap and there's nothing wrong about this per se, it is a problem that can be fixed with study, but it also means that you need someone to guide you through some server configs more advanced than it appears you're currently at, and this site, with its narrowly focused Q&A format doesn't really work for that.

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know. I am quite advanced on development but i have very little knowledge on servers in general! I'll get back to it